# How to solve this error about sending mail via PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to send mail via php code, but i don't know why it doesn't work, i always got this warning :

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "127.0.0.1" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in
>   php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\send mail.php on line 8

and i downloaded hmail server, the error is gone, and no error appears , but the mail does not been sent.

I'm using **EasyPHP 5.3.8.1** on windows 10.
My code is :

```
<?php
$to = "example1@hotmail.com";
$subject = "anything";
$txt = "Hello world! My first mail with PHP";
$headers = "From: example2@hotmail.com" . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: You are in localhost, You may use [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: Are doing this on your local host machine? or is it on a server?

Comment: it is on local host 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `mail` command internally uses the os built-in `mail` program to send mails (by default). On Windows, this behaves a little bit differently, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

By default, this requires a local mail server running that takes the mail and forwards it to the destination.

I recommend using HTMLMimeMail5 https://github.com/matthiask/swisdk2/blob/master/lib/contrib/htmlMimeMail5/htmlMimeMail5.php or PEAR::Mail_MIME, as stated in the documentation:

> If intending to send HTML or otherwise Complex mails, it is recommended to use the PEAR package » PEAR::Mail_Mime.

If you really intend to use a local mail server, well, you need to make sure it is running.

Comment: how to do that ?